# What happens at the end of Uppi 2?

Tags: analysis, ending, uppi-2

Why does the movie [Uppi 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uppi_2) end abruptly? What is the conclusion from the movie? Or does it just show to not to worry about anything i.e even the movie, which is the actual message of the movie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From abhijitpuranik on [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4833824/board/nest/247640035?ref_=tt_bd_4):

> Uppi 2 Decoded One Hundred Percent :-)
>
> 1) After Upendra 1 climax, Naanu detaches himself from all ego & selfishness and kills all his desires for wealth, leisure & worldly ties. He walks away from his past world of impurity and goes to Himalayas and becomes an Aghori or Sadhu. He meditates for years and gets 'Gnyaanodhaya' or 'Enlightenment' and transforms into a New person called 'Neenu', who is completely contrast to his past identity. In a way he has taken a rebirth. He comes back to his Village and starts living with his parents and family whom he had abandoned during his childhood. He doesn't want anything to himself, he only works for and helps others, which gives him happiness.
>
> 2) A millionaire German business tycoon Richards marries an Indian woman Mandaakini. Saleem will be their personal assistant. Richards dies in an accident and Saleem takes over all of Richards wealth and property.
>
> 3) Mandaakini runs from Saleem who wants to get the ownership of all the property which belongs to her. She leaves after writing a 'Will' stating that if a person called 'Neenu' who 'does not think' marries her daughter 'Kushi' then all property goes to him. She has secretly raised her daughter somewhere far away.
>
> 4) The will comes into the possession of the Police Department & then passed on to the Central Investigation Department & everyone including the CID officers and the Police Department led by Shinde have their eyes on the will. The word even spreads to Saleem who is now a Don in Dubai.
>
> 5) A girl called Lakshmi (Kristina) comes looking for Neenu in his village, as she is curious about his personality after hearing about him from her Psychology professor. Also Saleem sends his assistant Malpe Baala (LK Bala ;) ) and his goons to search Neenu. Also the Police (Shinde, and 2 constables) & another rowdy (Boda) are also behind Neenu. All of them are behind Neenu because his name is in the Will and they want to catch him / kill him so that they can get hold of all the property.
>
> 6) Saleem & Baala dont know that Lakshmi herself is Kushi, who has been secretly raised by her mother. They dont know that this is the same girl who is mentioned in the will along with Neenu. Lakshmi comes searching for Neenu in his village and falls for him. The police try to arrest Neenu but they are stopped by a phone call from a 'higher influence'. This phone call is made by some higher officials by Mandaakini's influence, who is also watching over Neenu, her potential son in law.
>
> 7) The dons and goons see Lakshmi flirting with Neenu. Now what they want is, somehow if they make Neenu to marry this girl Lakshmi, then the rule of the Will can be broken i.e. Neenu wont marry Kushi so he wont get the property. So they call Lakshmi to the boat and tell her get engaged with Neenu and marry him somehow which she readily agrees since she also wants the same as she loves him. They give her a bunglow which is in their control and tell her to act like it is hers so that Neenu family comes in desire for wealth and force him to marry her.
>
> 8 ) Meanwhile the police officer Shinde investigates the past life of this Neenu and finds out from an Aghori in Himalaya that Neenu once used to live there as a Sadhu after leaving behind his past life of Naanu. Shinde wants the money for himself and does not want Saleem to succeed in his plan, so he makes Lakshmi's friend Sheela (Parul) to tell her a false story about Neenu that he cheated her and tried to kill her. All the flashback story with Parul in Himalayas are all cooked up stories forcibly made to be told by the Police.
>
> 9) Saleem's ships carrying cocaine are blasted. LK Baala thinks that 'Naanu' whom he had encountered in the Past (in Upendra movie) attacked his ships. Baala & the CID officers (who are also behind the property) get an Unknown call from a person to come to a location where he has hidden Kushi (which is a trap for Saleem, Baala & the gangsters). Lakshmi gets an Unknwon call from the same person to come to a bunglow. This person who gave unknown calls is revealed to be Neenu.
>
> 10) Naanu is just an illusion of LK Baala as he is constantly haunted by his Past and his brain always keeps thinking about Past. That is why he is attacked by Past Upendra i.e. Naanu and ends up in a hospital. The CID officers who are also behind money, have brains which think only about Future, so they imagine or predict that a secret agent aka Unknown (who they think is Neenu) fighting off Saleem's goons and capturing Saleem. It is left to the audience to interpret what happens to Saleem, whether the CID officers themselves catch or kill Saleem in the ensuing gunfire, since the Future is 'Unknown'. Past is 'Illusion' and Future is 'Unknown' is the message of this Baala-Naanu-CID-Saleem-Unknown fight scene in the climax.
>
> 11) The secret is Lakshmi's other name will be Kushi (kept as secret by her mother). It was Neenu's plan to give unknown calls to the gangsters & CID officers to come to the location so they can fight with themselves while he can safely meet or get Kushi ;) In the end Upendra aka Neenu asks her "ivaag neen kushi thaane (Are you Kushi / Happy now ? for which she says yes) that means the Will is now satisfied. Neenu marries Kushi and will get all the property but he will not use it for himself he will continue to do service for others using all the wealth he has. LK Baala is stuck in the Past and haunted by Naanu and CID officers are still predicting the Future. Only Neenu & Kushi are living in present, which is the ideal way of living life is what the message in this film.
>
> 12) Lakshmi (Money) is only Kushi (Happiness) and Kushi (Happiness) is only Lakshmi (Money) means if we are content with whatever amount of wealth or money or Lakshmi we have then automatically Kushi (happiness) will come.
>
> 13) The climax - :D Since the Police Officer (Shinde) thinks that Lakshmi (money) & Kushi (Happiness) are two different women or entities, he is not able to find either of them in the end ;) Since 'Neenu' (us - the audience) already got Kushi (happiness), he asks us (the audience) in the end facing towards the camera saying where is Kushi, then we are shown the white screen - this white screen is nothing but a representation of the audience - or Neenu ;) This white screen is already shown in the beginning of the movie and the movie again ends with it - representing the 'Kaala Chakra' or the Cycle of Time.
>
> ---
>
> Some assumptions and interpretations to support this version :
>
> 1) In this version we should interpret or assume that it is Manaadkini who is protecting Neenu from getting arrested by the police. it is also Mandaakini's men who kill the blackmailer of Neenu's sister.
>
> 2) The future or Unknown or the special agent Upendra whom we have although assumed as only an imagination, can in reality actually be existing, the person who first saved Mandaakini from Saleem's men and discovered her 'Will' which he handed over to the department, but he may not necessarily be looking exactly like Neenu, it is only the CID officers who imagine him that he looks like (or is) Neenu.
>
> 3) Also, it is he who blasted Saleem's Ships. Since the future is not set, it may be possible that he even eventually catches Saleem as imagined by the CID officers. In any case Saleem will either die or get caught :p
>
> 4) we can also interpret that it is this special agent who gave the unknown calls to gangsters and CID to come to the climax location and he gave unknown call to Kristina to go and meet Neenu in the bunglow. He is helping Kristina or Kushi to meet her soulmate as per the will written by her mother which he read in Mandaakini's house.
>
> 5) It can also be he who made the phone call to stop the police from arresting Neenu, and it can be he who got blackmailer of Neenu's sister killed.